# C#: Deleting row in DataTable does not apply to data bank

Tags: c#, sqlite

My task should be quite simple but after hours and hours I must admit I'm completely stuck!

I simply want to delete a `datarow` from a `datatable`. My datatable is a copy of the table in my current dataset in a SQLite databank. It is mandatory to use the `table.row.Delete()` method. I am aware that `delete()` just marks the row to be deleted upon table update.

Below is the code I'm currently using:

I retrieve my data via:

```
    public DataTable GetTable(string tableName)
    {
        string connectionPath = dbVariables.ConnectionString;

        try
        {

            SQLiteConnection myConnection = new  SQLiteConnection(connectionPath);

            myConnection.Open();
            string cmdStr = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;

            DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
            SQLiteDataAdapter myAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmdStr, myConnection);

            myAdapter.FillSchema(myTable, SchemaType.Source); 

            myTable.Columns[dbVariables.ClassesID].AutoIncrement = true; 
            myTable.Columns[dbVariables.ClassesID].AutoIncrementSeed = 1; 
            myTable.Columns[dbVariables.ClassesID].AutoIncrementStep = 1; 

            myAdapter.Fill(myTable);

            myConnection.Close();

            return myTable;

        }
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here I manipulate my data:

```
if (myResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //killTable.AcceptChanges();
    DataRow[] dr = killTable.Select("" + cmVariables.ClassName + " = '" + cmbClasses.Text + "'");

    //First I need to evaluate the row index of the row I want to delete
    string indexName = (killTable.Rows.IndexOf(dr[0])).ToString();
    int i = Int32.Parse(indexName);

    // And we are done - I got my row index
    DataRow modifiedRow = killTable.Rows[i];

    killTable.Rows[i].Delete();

    //I inserted this messagebox just to see the rowstatus - and yes, it is marked as deleted on runtime...
    MessageBox.Show(killTable.Rows[i].RowState);

    // I refer to this in the text below
    killTable.AcceptChanges();

    killClass_Execution(killTable, cmbClasses.Text, ShortClassNm);
}
```

And at least the code to update my datatable back to the databank:

```
public void UpdateTable(string tableName, DataTable sourceTable, bool newOrEdit)
    {          
        try
        {
            string connectionPath = dbVariables.ConnectionString;
            //Connection erstellen --> der connectString gibt dabei den Pfad an.
            SQLiteConnection myConnection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionPath);

            myConnection.Open();

            //Einen Befehls-String erstellen, der das UPDATE-Command auslöst
            // UPDATE cm_ClassTest SET className = userEditInput WHERE className = 'oldClassName'
            string myUpdateString = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + "";

            SQLiteDataAdapter myAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(myUpdateString, myConnection);

            SQLiteCommandBuilder comBuild = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(myAdapter);

            myAdapter.DeleteCommand = comBuild.GetDeleteCommand(true);
            myAdapter.UpdateCommand = comBuild.GetUpdateCommand(true);
            myAdapter.InsertCommand = comBuild.GetInsertCommand(true);

            myAdapter.Update(sourceTable);

            myConnection.Close();

            if (newOrEdit == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Klasse erstellt!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Klasse aktualisiert!");
            }

        }
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }

    }
```

In the code block for manipulating data you will find the `AcceptChanges()` method. At this time, there may have been no other changes appeared to my datatable - so after app start, deleting a row may be the users first action.

Also: each entry in my dataset is unique (school classes that are labeled with a unique class name).

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Regards,

Aran

Comment: so, how does _myAdapter.DeleteCommand_ look like?

Comment: @TaW - As far as I know myAdapter.DeleteCommand = comBuild.GetDeleteCommand(true) should do the trick? (It's in the third code block, close to the end) --> I'm not sure about this, but do I need a special delete command despite this one?

Comment: Can you look into its properties? you should be able the see the delete sql there..

Comment: I will check on properties, as soon as I am at my workstation again. I checked the rowproperties on step by step debug - the row is there and is marked as deleted. AcceptChanges() however seems to have no effect. Could you find any critical lines in my code? I am not a 100% sure, if I got the whole update datatable thing correctly... thanks for hanging on to it!

Comment: It hink Acceptchange is more for entering new data. You can look into the  myAdapter.DeleteCommand property to see its sql.At least that is how is is for a [sqlDataadapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)..

Comment: Can you specify for what I should watch out? As I type in myAdapter, intelisense will show up with DeleteCommand, which itself has no further properties - I can asign it to my commandbuilder and set the GetDeleteCommand to 'true'. I found this[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/generating-commands-with-commandbuilders) on learn.microsoft.com - I'm not sure if my code holds true to all that's stated there...

Comment: You should use the debugger to look at it right after is has been filled !!

Answer (score 0):

OK - so I succeeded (finally). Debugging showed no issues, except for AcceptChanges() which got a call but did not result in actually deleting the dataRow.

All I can think of right now is that my primary approach to it was part of the problem: I get my DataTable right from the DataBase, do all the manipulations with it, and then send it back to DB via Update (see my update method above). The SQLite CommandBuilder seems not capable of interpreting my DAtaRow which is by then flagged 'Deleted', but kind of rubber-stamps it to the end of the method without throwing an exception.

By doing so I tried the GetChanges-Method:

```
 DataRow[] dr = killTable.Select("" + cmVariables.ClassName + " = '" + cmbClasses.Text + "'");

            string indexName = (killTable.Rows.IndexOf(dr[0])).ToString();

            int i = Int32.Parse(indexName);

            killTable.Rows[i].Delete();

            DataTable killItTable = killTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted);

            killClass_Execution(killItTable, cmbClasses.Text, ShortClassNm);
```

Now it's working - the copy of killTable (killItTable - stupid I know, but first thing I do tomorrow morning is give it better names :) ) provides info for the sql commandbuilder which seems to be recognized by it. 
Whatever it is - it now works.

I think this is not supposed to happen - if someone can come up with any good suggestions, on how to improve my approach, I shall be glad.
best regards